# traverse to element when knowing at least one in same hiearch. structure using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having following html structure

```
<tr>       
   <td>
      <input class="check-box" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"    checked="checked">
   </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td>
      <a href="/data/Edit/1">Edit</a>|
      <a href="/data/Details/1">Details</a>|
      <a href="/data/Delete/1">Delete</a>|
      <a id="myAction_1" onclick="myAction(1)">TakeAction</a>
    </td>
</tr>

function myAction(someId){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            dataType:'text',
            url: "/mydata/someaction/",
            data: { id: someId}
        }).done(function( msg ) {                
            $("#myAction_"+someId).text(msg);  
            // change checkbox here value to check or unchecked          
        });
    }
```

How can traverse in myAction in done method to checkbox element knowing `#myAction_"+someId` without assigning explicit id to checkbox id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `closest` method to find the table row, then locate the input from there. You can use the reference to the current element instead of an identity:

```
<a id="myAction_1" onclick="myAction(this)">TakeAction</a>
```

Then use it in the function:

```
function myAction(element){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        dataType:'text',
        url: "/mydata/someaction/",
        data: { id: someId}
    }).done(function( msg ) {                
        $("#myAction_"+someId).text(msg);  
        var check = $(element).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]');
        check.prop('checked', true); // make the checkbox checked
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var checkboxElement = $("#myAction_"+someId).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0) > input[type='checkbox']")
```

Comment: ok, I tried to use this element to change property using checkboxElement .prop('checked', true); nothing is returned as error in console but values is not changed. any idea

Comment: I see that your checkbox is `disabled`. If it is disabled, I guess you cannot change the property.

Comment: I take back my comment :) Your checkbox is already checked!! Try to do `checkboxElement .prop('checked', false); ` which should uncheck the checkbox.